# If I write data into different column family of hbase concurrently, whether there is mutual influence

Tags: multithreading, hbase, column-family

In my application, every thread is responsible for writing data into one column family, these threads may not start at the same time, but they may write data synchronously.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @orion78fr The write speed is not stable, sometime it is very slow.